# bootstrap navbar : overiding font color

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, background-color

I want to change background color and font color of my bootstrap navbar, with a simple css code:

```css
#mainNav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: transparent;
     color: #333;
        position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
        top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
        width: 100%; /* Full width */
    }
    .navbar a{
     color: #333;
    }
```

I get the transparent background, and font color is white (instead of black)

My bootstrap navbar code is as folows:

```html
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="img/abc.png" alt="logo" width="72" height="68" id="logo">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio_sectors">Sectors</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#my_carousel">References</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed targeting the elements correctly, and your rule for `.navbar a` is getting applied. The problem is that Bootstrap is providing **[higher specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**: `.navbar-default .navbar-brand` is overwriting `.navbar a`. As such, you can use `.navbar-default a.navbar-brand` to target the logo instead of `.navbar a`, providing higher specificity yourself.

Note that your `#mainNav` selector is indeed applying all of your custom rules.

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
#mainNav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #333;
  position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
}

.navbar-default a.navbar-brand {
  color: #333;
  color: red /* To clearly showcase the override */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"><img src="img/abc.png" alt="logo" width="72" height="68" id="logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="hidden">
          <a href="#page-top"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio_sectors">Sectors</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#my_carousel">References</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thanks a lot, Obsidian, for letting me know about this Higher Specificity rule, as I am a totally bootstrap newby. Since I am using a bootstrap template, trying to understand all the css behind it is just overwhelming. 

I've changed my code according to your suggestion, and altough I can make it work when isolated, it won't run again once in my template.

I guess it's again about Higher Specificity somewhere in my template code, but can't find it...

Comment: No problem; it's something you'll certainly want to keep in mind with CSS! Bootstrap does indeed add a lot of custom rules (not just in `bootstrap.css`, but also in files like `navbar.less`). I'd recommend using the F12 Developer Tools inspector (checking the 'Rules') to see which rules are getting added. 'Computed' will show you which one is getting applied. Start from this working example as a 'base', and slowly apply things until it stops working; then you know the problem, and can check the rules. Don't forget you can use `!important` to override, but that should only be a last resort ;)